What is the difference between subjunctive and indicative mood?
I have two sentences:

If the distance between the two points is the same, no further experiments will be necessary.
If the distance between the two points be the same, no further experiments will be necessary.

What is the difference between them?

The latter is quite dated, and the former is entirely acceptable (sayeth the research mathematician).

There are lots of existing questions about using subjunctive after if: such as this. this, this. Do you have a specific difference in mind that's not covered by existing questions?
